# Parallel Activity containing Receive in Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation-4.5

I have a workflow in which I require parallel paths whilst awaiting input from users.
However, the workflow never responds to the received messages in the branches.

If I remove the 3 'Receive' activities, the workflow continues along all 3 branches, and the Parallel Activity completes ok (no CompletionCondition is specified).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks, Dave
[image: Workflow showing parallel paths]

Comment: Ok, this is getting weird....

Comment: After lots of trying of different things, I now know that if I add a Receive Message activity which I copy verbatim from elsewhere in my workflow, it works ok.
If I then _rename_ that new Receive activity's method name (then re-build the workflow, and also re-build the client to use that new name), the workflow flatly refuses to respond to calls to that new method.
What is happening? What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Receive activity's "Correlates On" property. The operation itself was renamed, but the XPath expression still contains the old operation name. Either edit the expression or remove it and create it again.